# Sql query find rows with value of 2 dependent of count of another value in row

Tags: sql

I have a table of employees listed with their position numbers and a field called position_sequence that assigns an employee's positions as either 1 or 2. So only IF an employee has 2 positions, one should be assigned 1 and another row should have value of 2.

However, I would like to find a query to find all issues of the data where there is only 1 position for an employee, but the position sequence is 2 instead of 1.

Correct data (2 positions):

```
employee   position   sequence
------------------------------------
bob        builder    1
bob        cleaner    2
```

Incorrect example (1 position but marked as 2 instead of 1):

```
 employee   position   sequence
------------------------------------
    sally   builder    2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where sequence = 2 and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.employee = t.employee and t2.sequence = 1);
```

If you wanted a general "is the sequence missing", then generate the sequence and show exceptions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employee order by sequence) as imputed_sequence
      from t
     ) t
where imputed_sequence <> sequence;
```